# Understanding the notion of the fundamental group

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, fundamental-groups

Can anyone explain what we mean by homotopy classes and for how can for example the fundamental group of the real number line be 0? And what exactly does the fundamental group consist of?

Comment: It sounds like you should start by reading some book on the topic or go to lectures. I  recommend you "Algebraic Topology" by Hatcher, it's online.

Comment: The introductory topology book by Munkres also has a few chapters on the fundamental group.

Comment: So you have heard of homotopy classes and know that the fundamental group of the real number line is $0$: where did you get that information? If you give us some context about that, then we can perhaps help you.

Comment: @Arthur Not just a "few" chapters. The second part of Munkres book gives pretty good knowledge about the fundamental group. And everything there is rigorous, unlike in Hatcher's book. (which has nothing but hand waving). To OP, I definitely recommend Munkres.

Comment: @Mark Hatcher may not be the most rigorous text, but I have yet to see a book with better exercises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a full, rigorous, Mathematical description of what is meant by the fundamental group you will need to watch some lectures or read some notes. But I guess an informal explanation would help with understanding intuitively what it all means.

Two continuous functions, ${f : X\to Y}$ and ${g:X\to Y}$ are said to be homotopic, written as ${f\simeq g}$, if there is some nice continuous way to "deform" $f$ into $g$. It turns out that the ${\simeq}$ symbol actually gives us an equivalence relation. That means that given some continuous function $f$, we can "slot it into" exactly one class of functions that are all homotopic to each other basically.

Now - a loop in a topological space is a nice continuous path that starts and ends at the same point. Loops are continuous functions, and so these have their own "homotopy classes". In other words - every loop can be fit nicely into exactly one class of loops, and all loops within their classes can be "deformed" nicely into one another.

With this in mind, the fundamental group is essentially the set of these "loop homotopy classes", where we define some nice group operation on these classes of loops (we do the "path product").

The reason the fundamental group of the real line, ${\pi_1(\mathbb{R})}$, is $0$ ($0$ in this context means "the group with just the identity element") is because any loop in ${\mathbb{R}}$ can be deformed continuously into any other loop in ${\mathbb{R}}$ (it's not difficult to see this). So there is only one "loop" class, and it must be the identity element (since groups need at the minimum the identity element).

Comment: Oh I think this actually helped a lot, so if I understand this correctly because all loops are homotopic through the straight line homotopy (I assume) there is only one equivalence class that they belong to and that makes the fundamental group trivial?

Comment: @chris exactly that yes, although I'm not sure I understand what you mean by straight line homotopy. But yes, every loop can be deformed continuously into any over loop, meaning that every loop belongs to the same equivalence class. So the fundamental group has to be trivial, as you said. I can write the proof that every loop can be deformed continuously into each other upon request

Comment: @Riemann'sPointyNose: you are being far to kind to the OP, who is now continuing to bate you. The straight line homotopy is the one that shows that any star-shaped subset of $\Bbb{R}^n$ is contractible. The OP should tell us more about the context, and only then can we usefully try to help.

Comment: I dont know how to use MathJax unfortunately to tell you what I mean by straight line homotopy, but I have read it in Munkres' and Hatcher's book as a term, but please prove this if its not too much trouble, just so I can confirm that I understood it